# ANTLR4: How to set different context within rule for the same tag?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have such grammar:

```
grammar SearchQuery;

queryDeclaration                        : predicateGroupItem predicateGroupItemWithBooleanOperator* ;
predicateGroupItemWithBooleanOperator   : groupOperator predicateGroupItem ;
predicateGroupItem                      : LEFT_BRACKET variable variableDelimiter
                                                expression expressionWithBoolean* RIGHT_BRACKET ;

variable                                : VARIABLE_STRING ;
variableDelimiter                       : VAR_DELIMITER  ;

expressionWithBoolean                   : boolOperator expression ;

expression                              : value ;

value                                   : polygonType;

boolOperator                            : or
                                        ;

or                                      : OR ;

groupOperator                           : AND ;

polygonType                             : POLYGON LEFT_BRACKET pointList (POLYGON_DELIMITER pointList)* RIGHT_BRACKET ;
longType                                : LONG ;
doubleType                              : DOUBLE ;

pointList                               : point
                                        | LEFT_BRACKET point ( POLYGON_DELIMITER point)* RIGHT_BRACKET
                                        ;

point                                   : latitude longitude ;

latitude                                : longType
                                        | doubleType
                                        ;

longitude                               : longType
                                        | doubleType
                                        ;

POLYGON                                 : [pP] [oO] [lL] [yY] [gG] [oO] [nN] ;


LONG                                    : DIGIT+ ;

DOUBLE                                  : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*
                                        | '.' DIGIT+
                                        ;

AND                                     : [aA] [nN] [dD] ;
OR                                      : COMMA
                                        | [oO] [rR]
                                        ;

VARIABLE_STRING                         : [a-zA-Z0-9.]+ ;
COMMA                                   : ',' ;
POLYGON_DELIMITER                       : ';' ;
VAR_DELIMITER                           : ':' ;

RIGHT_BRACKET                           : ')' ;
LEFT_BRACKET                            : '(' ;

WS                                      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

fragment DIGIT                          : [0-9] ;
```

Problem is that I can't use COMMA tag with different rules simultaneously in *polygonType*, *pointList* rules (I need to use COMMA except for POLYGON_DELIMITER) and *boolOperator* rule (there is COMMA used)
Other words, if we will change POLYGON_DELIMITER to COMMA and 
test such grammar with a value like this

```
(polygons: polygon(20 30.4, 23.4 23),
           polygon(20 30.4, 23.4 23),
           polygon(20 30.4, 23.4 23))
```

we will get an error

```
mismatch input: ',' expecting {',', ')'}
```

I will happy if somebody will help me to understand the problem.

P.S. if we will not change current grammar the value for the testing it is

```
(poligons: polygon(20 30.4; 23.4 23),
           polygon(20 30.4; 23.4 23),
           polygon(20 30.4; 23.4 23))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of these rules:

```
OR                                      : COMMA
                                        | [oO] [rR]
                                        ;

COMMA                                   : ',' ;
```

the lexer will never produce a `COMMA` token since it is already matched by the `OR` token. And because `OR` is defined before `COMMA`, it gets precedence.

That is what the error message `mismatch input: ',' expecting {',', ')'}` really means. In other words: `mismatch input: OR expecting {COMMA, RIGHT_BRACKET}`

What you should do (if the OR operator can be either "or" or ",") is let the parser rule `or` match the `COMMA`:

```
or                                      : OR
                                        | COMMA
                                        ;

OR                                      : [oO] [rR]
                                        ;

COMMA                                   : ',' ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bart Kiers. Yes, you are right.